# how to access object anywhere in the application after startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I have some countries list in map in a class. Now I want to access this map in my application in some other classes.

Basically I want this map available throughout the application.

I am getting countries list in boot application just after startup. But able to set it to application scope. I am using spring boot and web.

Below is my code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FinalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(FinalApplication.class).run(args);
        Country cfg = context.getBean(Country.class);
        CountryDataLoader loader = new CountryDataLoader(cfg);
}

@ApplicationScope
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CountryDataLoader {

    Map<String,List<String>> regionMap = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String,List<String>> languageMap = new HashMap<>();
public List<String> countryListByAmericaRegion () {
        //System.out.println(myConfig.getList());
        List<CountryBean> list = myConfig.getList();
        Iterator<CountryBean> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            CountryBean bean = it.next();
            if(bean.getRegion().equals(AMERICAS)) {
                byAmericaRegion.add(bean.getCountryName());
            }
        }
        regionMap.put(AMERICAS, byAmericaRegion);
        //System.out.println(byAmericaRegion);
        return byAmericaRegion;
    }

}
```

In countrydataLoader class I am loading all country data. how to access those two maps in some other restcontrollers?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountryDaoLoader` is a spring bean and you can get the instance of a spring bean from application context as shown below.

> ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(CountryDataLoader.class);